# Django ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.") error

Tags: python, django, settings

I currently got a Django project and have been tasked to run it locally. Currently it is very large and so the settings e.t.c can get confusing. I'm trying to run manage.py runserver and it keeps giving me secret key not configured error. (Although my secret key is configured in settings like it ususally is) I read a previous post that this could be due to circular dependencies so i went through the settings code and found something that COULD possibly be an issue but I'm not completely sure.

```
### CELERY ####
CELERY_IMPORTS = [
    'X.Y.tasks',
    'mailchimp_synchronisation.tasks'
]
```

When I open these files from their respective folders the first import I see is:

```
from django.conf import settings
```

I'm not sure if this is what's causing the error because:

1. It seems like just information and not actually running this piece of code
2. My settings file is saved inside a folder called settings and is saved as base.py instead of just settings.py

I've tried adding the secret key to my docker compose, adding the settings file as well in the environment but it always seems to give the same error

Comment: It is very hard to understand the problem just by this information, what I can suggest is, check for the Django `SECRET_KEY` in `base.py` or `local.py/dev.py`. It is possible that the value of it being set by the environment variables. If it is not there and you want to generate a random one, you can serach and find a way. Also, I suggest to perform `docker build --no-cache` when you change the settings from `.env` files. Because, I faced similar issues with docker and I could solve it by new build!

Comment: Check as well if `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` (in `wsgi.py` or `asgi.py`) is pointing to your `base.py` settings file.